# Roscore wont run due to rosout not being built

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, ros

I am unable to roscore. It was working fine a while ago, however it is no working anymore. I have uninstalled and reinstalled ros melodic 2 times now but to no avail. this is what happens when I run roscore:

```
aditya@aditya-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK:~/catkin_ws$ roscore
... logging to /home/aditya/.ros/log/781e2678-995e-11ea-a38d-e0946779fe64/roslaunch-aditya-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK-5956.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://aditya-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK:46667/
ros_comm version 1.13.0


SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: melodic
 * /rosversion: 1.13.0

NODES

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [5967]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://aditya-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK:11311/

setting /run_id to 781e2678-995e-11ea-a38d-e0946779fe64



ERROR: rosout is not built. Please run 'rosmake rosout'



failed to start core service [/rosout]
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
[master] killing on exit
```

when I run rosmake rosout:rosmake rosout

```
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                                                                                                                                                    
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['rosout']                                                                                                                                                                     
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/aditya/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20200519-045259                                                                                                                          
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['rosout'] to:
['rosout']                                                                                                                                                                
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> catkin [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                           
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< catkin ROS_NOBUILD in package catkin
 No Makefile in package catkin                                                                                                                       
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> genmsg [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                           
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< genmsg ROS_NOBUILD in package genmsg
 No Makefile in package genmsg                                                                                                                       
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> genlisp [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                          
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> genpy [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                            
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> gencpp [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                           
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< genlisp ROS_NOBUILD in package genlisp
 No Makefile in package genlisp                                                                                                                    
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> geneus [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                           
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> gennodejs [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                        
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< geneus ROS_NOBUILD in package geneus
 No Makefile in package geneus                                                                                                                       
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> cpp_common [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                       
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< gencpp ROS_NOBUILD in package gencpp
 No Makefile in package gencpp                                                                                                                       
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> ros_environment [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                  
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< genpy ROS_NOBUILD in package genpy
 No Makefile in package genpy                                                                                                                          
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> cmake_modules [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                    
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< cpp_common ROS_NOBUILD in package cpp_common
 No Makefile in package cpp_common                                                                                                           
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< gennodejs ROS_NOBUILD in package gennodejs
 No Makefile in package gennodejs                                                                                                              
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rostime [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                          
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> message_generation [ make ]                                                                                                                                                               
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< cmake_modules ROS_NOBUILD in package cmake_modules
 No Makefile in package cmake_modules                                                                                                  
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< ros_environment ROS_NOBUILD in package ros_environment
 No Makefile in package ros_environment                                                                                            
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosmake [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                          
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rospack [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                          
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rostime ROS_NOBUILD in package rostime
 No Makefile in package rostime                                                                                                                    
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> roscpp_traits [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                    
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< message_generation ROS_NOBUILD in package message_generation
 No Makefile in package message_generation                                                                                   
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                          
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rospack ROS_NOBUILD in package rospack
 No Makefile in package rospack                                                                                                                    
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> xmlrpcpp [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                         
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< roscpp_traits ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_traits
 No Makefile in package roscpp_traits                                                                                                  
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosmake ROS_NOBUILD in package rosmake
 No Makefile in package rosmake                                                                                                                    
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> roscpp_serialization [ make ]                                                                                                                                                             
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                           
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang ROS_NOBUILD in package roslang
 No Makefile in package roslang                                                                                                                    
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< roscpp_serialization ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_serialization
 No Makefile in package roscpp_serialization                                                                             
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> message_runtime [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                  
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< xmlrpcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package xmlrpcpp
 No Makefile in package xmlrpcpp                                                                                                                 
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< roslib ROS_NOBUILD in package roslib
 No Makefile in package roslib                                                                                                                       
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosunit [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                          
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< message_runtime ROS_NOBUILD in package message_runtime
 No Makefile in package message_runtime                                                                                            
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                         
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                         
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosunit ROS_NOBUILD in package rosunit
 No Makefile in package rosunit                                                                                                                    
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< std_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package std_msgs
 No Makefile in package std_msgs                                                                                                                 
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosgraph_msgs [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                    
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbuild ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbuild
 No Makefile in package rosbuild                                                                                                                 
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                       
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosgraph_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph_msgs
 No Makefile in package rosgraph_msgs                                                                                                  
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosconsole ROS_NOBUILD in package rosconsole
 No Makefile in package rosconsole                                                                                                           
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                           
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< roscpp ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp
 No Makefile in package roscpp                                                                                                                       
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosout [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                           
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosout ROS_NOBUILD in package rosout
 No Makefile in package rosout                                                                                                                       
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                                                                                                                                                               
[ rosmake ] Built 27 packages with 0 failures.                                                                                                                                                                     
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                                                                                                                                                            
[ rosmake ] /home/aditya/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20200519-045259
```

please help me. i have a project to submit soon.
thanks in advance!

Comment: I have checked multiple websites and none seem to provide an answer. should I uninstall Ubuntu and install it again?

Comment: How did you install and uninstall ROS?

Comment: Did you install it from source? After following the instructions in the [ROS wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu) you should not need to build anything.

Uninstall what you installed and follow the instructions in the link I posted. With the commands that modify some files, check that the files have been modified correctly.

Comment: I followed this guide exactly.

Comment: I solved it and i have written an answer for the same, thanks @MRFalcon for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am new to ros so I had not realized this. the problem lied within my catkin workspace. so I deleted it and made a new one. this solved the problem.

```
... logging to /home/aditya/.ros/log/9112b5e4-99d7-11ea-b44d-e0946779fe64/roslaunch-aditya-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK-13672.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://aditya-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK:37647/
ros_comm version 1.14.5


SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: melodic
 * /rosversion: 1.14.5

NODES

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [13682]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://aditya-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK:11311/

setting /run_id to 9112b5e4-99d7-11ea-b44d-e0946779fe64
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [13693]
started core service [/rosout]
^C[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

A big thank you to  @MRFalcon for responding!
the issue had occurred due to a  plugin that  I had installed. therefore, I copied all my packages except the plugin, ran `catkin_make`, and then `roscore`. this solved it for me.

Comment: Clad that you managed to solve it, one command that would probably have indicated the problem would have been `roscd rosout`. Which should be taking you to the install space of the apt installed package `/opt/ros/kinetic/share/rosout`. `roscd` is a good command to keep in mind for the future, if you should experience weird issues of things not quite working as you think they should. Generally you can expect ROS to use the same package as the one that is found by `roscd`. If you have more than one package with the same name you can list them with `rospack list | grep package`